# Selenium ChromeDriver manage timeout

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Eager;

string[] options_list = new string[]
{
                "start-maximized",
                "enable-automation",
                //"--headless",
                "--no-sandbox",
                "--disable-infobars",
                "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
                "--disable-gpu",
                "enable-features=NetworkServiceInProcess"
};

options.AddArguments(options_list);

using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options))
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);


 wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Name("lgin"))).Click();

 // After lgin clicked
 // Page may load for 3 to 5 minutes due to huge data processing

 wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("Img2"))).Click();
}
```

During the 3 to 5 minutes wait, I will always hit the exception error below.

The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:50696/session/b8dbc3609bdb0d779c81886942342b6d/element/1fc37ce8-a8a0-4a51-84ed-18828edf7b46/click timed out after 60 seconds.

I tried to add the codes below:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

But the timed out times still 60 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried with `WebDriverWait`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

It's quite probable that you've hit this issue: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4874

> Each driver class has a constructor overload that allows you to set the timeout for
>   each command. Here is an example for the FirefoxDriver to set the command timeout to
>   5 minutes:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(), null, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

> You can find similar constructor overloads for InternetExplorerDriver, ChromeDriver,
>   and RemoteWebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 using (IWebDriver driver = new 
 ChromeDriver(options))
{
   Thread.Sleep(8000);    // or higher
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);        
   driver.FindElement(By.Name("lgin")).Click();
   // Thread.Sleep(8000);    // or higher
   // try this upper line if you need it
   driver.FindElement(By.Id("Img2")).Click();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this, but there are times the queried data is lesser and the respond is faster, so it will be a waste of time to wait a fixed timing.